# Android Studio - DatePicker in AlertDialog, null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I have an activity in my app, where I want the user to pick the date from a DatePicker, which is contained in an AlertDialog. In the AlertDialog, I have set a view, to an xml layout file (, which contains only a LinearLayout, with a single DatePicker.

The code is really simple, and looks like this, just below onCreate().

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setView(R.layout.activity_alertdialog_date);
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.Activity_AlertDialog_SetStartDate);
//  ... The rest of the AlertDialog, with buttons and all that stuff
alert.create().show()
```

The layout shows up in the AlertDialog, and that part works great.
However, when I try to add this line, I get a null object reference error.

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Here is the error message.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.DatePicker.setMinDate(long)' on a null object reference

How can I fix this, or improve my code in another way?
I really appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you trying to use this line `datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);`? Is `datePicker` within scope?

Comment: It is the very next line. This is all in a method that I'm calling at the end of onCreate(). So I'm calling the method in the line just below setContentView(...)

Comment: Sidenote to the question: you can chain your AlertDialog.Builder calls, i.e. `AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(R.layout.my_layout).setButtonPositive(R.string.sweet_text).create().show()` to make your code a little more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `findViewById` is looking in the wrong place for the DatePicker view. Calling `findViewById` in an activity will call it on the Activity's layout hierarchy, not the dialog's layout.  You need to inflate the layout for the alert dialog first, and then get a reference to the view. This can be acheived in a couple ways.

Probably the easiest is to inflate the view and get the reference before showing the dialog:

```
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_alertdialog_date, false);
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.Activity_AlertDialog_SetStartDate);

AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setView(dialogView);
//  ... The rest of the AlertDialog, with buttons and all that stuff
alert.create().show();
```

You could also get the view from the alert dialog after it's been created:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setView(R.id.Activity_AlertDialog_SetStartDate);
//  ... The rest of the AlertDialog, with buttons and all that stuff
AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();

dialog.show();
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Activity_AlertDialog_SetStartDate);
```